# Check if method is deprecated

Tags: objective-c

Is there any possibility to programmatically detect if a particular method is deprecated in the current version of system? Thanks

Comment: Checking for deprecation is done at compile time, not run time. You should probably provide a bit more context to your question.

Comment: @rmaddy do you mean i can use conditional compilation in order not to include calls to deprecated methods?

Comment: I mean you need to provide some details. What class/method are you talking about? What is your Base SDK and your Deployment Target?

Comment: BTW - read the [SDK Compatibility Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000163i).

Comment: @rmaddy i'm asking just in general. i've been wondering if it's possible or not

Comment: Your question is too vague and lacking any context to provide an answer. Again, read the document I linked above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no any way to programmatically detect if a particular method is deprecated in the current version of system. The only thing you can get to know through warning message that your method is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

warnings are based on your deployment target.
set the Deployment Target to the latest version.
Do a build from the Product menu, see all the warnings.

Comment: Why do this? If the Deployment target supports a method, there is no need to do anything even it has been deprecated in the Base SDK.

Comment: I don't wanna see warnings. I want my app to know about them

Answer (score 0):

You (and others getting here) may be trying to ask a slightly different question - how can you check to see if a deprecated method (aMethod:) of a non deprecated class (aClass) is still available at runtime?  You can do that with:

```
if([aClass instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(aMethod:)]){
   //   it's still available for use  
}
```